# FileOpenPicker in Viewmodel does not reflect changes in View after selecting multiple files

Tags: c#, uwp, synchronization, task-parallel-library, uwp-xaml

I am quite new to TPL and UWP and working with fileopenpicker control along with MVVM. I have a search button, on which i want to open a FileOpenPicker and select multiple files and then reflect it back on the view (using ListView).

Consider the code snippet for View:

```
  <Button x:Name="search" Content="select image"  RelativePanel.RightOf="imagepath" Command="{x:Bind addProduct.SearchCommand}"
                    Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20"></Button>

  <ListView x:Name="lstImages" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" DataContext="{Binding addProduct}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" TextAlignment="Left" >
                        </TextBlock>                            
                        <ProgressRing Width="20" Height="20" Foreground="Brown" x:Name="progress" IsActive="True" />
                        <Button Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Foreground="Brown" x:Name="Delete" Content="Delete" 
                                Command="{Binding ElementName=lstImages, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand }" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In ViewModel, I have initialize my Delegate command and then use the async method to select the files.

```
   public AddProductViewModel()
    {
        this.SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.SearchFiles);
    }

   private async void SearchFiles()
    {
        var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
        picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        var result = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
        var files = new ObservableCollection<StorageFile>();
        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in result.ToList())
            {
                files.Add(item);
            }
        }

        this.Files = files;

        //return files;
    }
```

The files selected using the picker is not reflected on the view, while during saving the property **Files** is available for saving with the correct data.

Thanks to provide suggestion, what is wrong with the code?

Comment: What type is `this.Files`?

Comment: this.Files is an ObservableCollection of StorageFile

public ObservableCollection<StorageFile> Files{get;set;}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, the same as in dozens of questions like this, do not assign to your `Files` property if it does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`just clear it and use `Add` to add the new items to it.

```
var result = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
if (result != null)
{
    Files.Clear()
    foreach (var item in result.ToList())
    {
        Files.Add(item);
    }
 }
```

Comment: It still don't works. I think the problem lies with the async method i.e SearchFiles. 
For the purpose, I have removed the ObservationCollection of StorageFile and use ObservableCollection of String and remove the async method, it starts working. 
But I need to use StorageFile, which picks content based on await method i.e await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

Comment: Thanks Igor. It just starts working for me. I used x:Bind instead of Binding in my view after making changes you have suggested and it works.